# Can extended Backus Naur Form (EBNF) describe an unordered set of values?

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, ebnf, context-free-language, ebnf-syntactic-exception

I'd like to define an unordered set of values using an Extended Backus-Naur Form (EBNF) context free grammar. It's easy to define an unordered list of values in EBNF, for example:

```
value = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';
list = value, {',', value};
```

However, I'm having doubts it can be done for an unordered set.

Below are examples of valid unordered sets of values:

```
A, B, C, D
A, B, D, C
A, D, C, B
...
D, C, B, A
```

Whilst invalid lists would be:

```
A, A, C, D
B, C, C, B
A, A, A, A
...
```

or lists of arbitrary length.

```
A, A, B, C, D, A
A, B, C, D, A, B, C, D
...
```

Comment: You can define sets by defining multiple non-terminal productions for each possible state of the set, but it would mean n! (or worse) productions :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* define unordered sets in EBNF, but only by listing all possible enumerations. That's impractical for sets larger than about two elements.

[The standard](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/s026153_ISO_IEC_14977_1996%28E%29.zip) -- to the extent that EBNF is a standardized notation -- allows you to use English (or any other language you feel comfortable with) to describe a sequence which is not otherwise describable. For example, the EBNF for EBNF includes this production:

```
syntactic exception
= ? a syntactic-factor that could be replaced 
    by a syntactic-factor containing no
    meta-identifiers
  ? ;
```

Similarly, you could write something like:

```
value = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';
list = value, {',', value};
set = ? a "list" where all "value"s are unique ? ;
```

or perhaps

```
set = ? a "list" with exactly three values
        where all "value"s are unique
      ? ;
```

That's not much use for building a parser generator, but it might be helpful for a human reader who understands the same language as you do.

For real parser generators, a common strategy is to allow any list, which might include repeated elements, and then reject invalid lists during semantic analysis. (Or even earlier. It's not a difficult analysis.)

Comment: Thanks @rici, good idea about setting the requirement of no repeating elements.